# Multiple cell input with conversion rate from another cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm having a problem with a small accounting sheet I'm currently working on in Google sheets. I have one cell where I can select the currency of income (GBP, USD, EUR) and another cell that auto-updates with the exchange rate on the day of transaction.

Now, I'm trying to figure out how I can automatically multiply the value that I enter into the income cell with the exchange rate to get the proper GBP amount.

Is that even possible?

[Sheet screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozwUy.png)

Answer (score 0):

To multiply one number by another use `*` between them.

Comment: I could do it this way but I don't want to do this manually each time. In an ideal scenario, I would want to input the income amount in whatever currency, e.g. $100, and then the cell auto-updates with the corresponding GBP amount by multiplying $100 with the exchange rate.

Comment: I could do something like `=F5*E5` where F5 is the income cell and E5 holds the corresponding exchange rate. However, if I then enter a value into F5 it overrides the formula. :/

Comment: Sure, but that would mean that for each income and expense type I have to have two cells, one with the formula and another one for the value. That makes the sheet quite messy but I guess I might have no other option here.